# Is mythic shield of faith’s deflection bonus maximum raised too?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, mythic-adventures

Under the mythic rules, there are mythic spells. [Mythic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/mythic-magic/augmented-spells/#Shield_of_Faith) [shield of faith](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shield-of-faith/) adds your tier to the deflection bonus from the base spell, but does that mean you hit the cap bonus provided much sooner? Or is that tier bonus on top of the spell bonus?

If I were a caster with 18 caster level tier 3 and cast mythic shield of faith, is the deflection bonus +5 or +8?

Answer (score 1):

### The deflection bonus is maxed at +5 as the augmented version does not increase this.

[Augmented Spells, Shield of Faith](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/mythic-magic/augmented-spells/#Shield_of_Faith) says:

> Add half your tier to the spell’s deflection bonus

[Shield of Faith](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shield-of-faith/)

> ...(maximum +5 deflection bonus at 18th level).

For example if you cast an [Augmented](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/mythic-magic/augmented-spells/#Shield_of_Faith) [Shield of Faith](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shield-of-faith/) as a level 10 Cleric with the max mythic rank of 10, the deflection bonus would be 3 (regular) + 5 (mythic) = **still 5 total**.

The rule can be found under [Effects of Mythic Spells](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/mythic-magic/)

> Unless a mythic spell’s description says it improves, replaces, or upgrades an effect of the non-mythic spell, or says that it creates an effect instead of the non-mythic spell’s effect, it retains all the effects of the non-mythic spell in addition to the effects of the mythic version.

Supporting this is [Augmented](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/mythic-magic/augmented-spells/#Anticipate_Peril) [Anticipate Peril](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/anticipate-peril/) which specifically calls out the increase to the maximum bonus.

> Add your tier to the spell’s initiative bonus and the maximum initiative bonus the spell can grant.

Comment: Removed my old incorrect post and added new one with the correct answer and rules quotations to support.

Comment: You shouldnt have deleted the old answer, you should have edited it. The new answer does not address the issue about quoting rules. You quoted a rule thats specific to mythic Anticipate Peril, not to mythic shield of faith. Sadly despite SOF most likely working this way, there is still nothing which directly says it does.

Comment: In the editing box it says to edit when you "clarify meaning without changing it" or "correct minor mistakes".  Neither of which this post was as it is the complete opposite decision of the previous post.

Comment: I admit I had not read it closely enough to have noticed you reversed stance. Sorry about that. Most of it was the same so I just skimmed but missed the most important.